# Google Analytics: Custom report showing conversions having visited specific page

Tags: google-analytics, report

I've been looking around and also played with custom reports but I don't find it: how to set up a custom report that shows the number of conversions in Google Analytics where the visitor has visited a particular page?

The idea is to gauge whether a particular page is increasing the likelihood of conversion.

So far, I've tried looking at conversions with a dimension of 'Page' and also the various levels ('Page path level *n*')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is "Advanced Segments":

Google's Docs: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017

Comment: An alternative would be to set up a goal for the url - which in a way isn't all that different from advanced segments but has a few nice pre-configured reports like funnel visualizations or goal flow (plus Goals themselved can be used for segmentation). http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032415